# How to perform student t test in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Is there any way to perform student t-test in pyspark because there is no method in ml.stat module.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to do a comparison in means with a binary variable denoting the two different groups, you can just use `LinearRegression` from `pyspark.ml.regression`. Regress the continuous variable on the binary variable, and then call `summary.tValues` on the fit model. This is identical to doing a comparison in means t test.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see t-test part of pyspark API's. It is present in the Java version as mentioned here [1]

You can build your own t-test model in python by looking at the chisquared implementation here [2], where they use the java apis to build a python class.

1 - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/stat/test/StudentTTest.html#StudentTTest--

2 - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/ml/stat.html